# Magento 2 : How to get selected simple product Id on checkout_card_add_after observer?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, event-observer, addtocart, associate-products

I want to get selected associated product id after an **checkout_cart_add_after** triggered. If any helps would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

I will be speaking for Magento 2.2.6

There is an event dispatch like this

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
    ['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]
;
```

inside the `addProduct` method of the `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class.

The `$result` variable that is dispatched, and will be available to you if you were to listen to the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event, is actually of type `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item`, i.e. this is the item that is added to the quote.

In this screenshot you will see all relevant data that you need. For example, in the `_data` array there is the `product_type` which in my example is `configurable`, but in the `sku`, this is the sku of the actual simple product that I have chosen.

[image]

And don't worry, here it will have the appropriate data if you need to extract data from a grouped or a bundle product. It is simply there, and this is what you should utilize.

So, the event again is `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, and you should be able to collect the data from the `Observer $observer` in your `execute` method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: what method should I need inject there to get the details of associated products in M2.2x